# Get employee who created product

Tags: product, prestashop-1.6, owner

Please,I'm using prestashop 1.6 and want to create on module. my question is: is it possible to get the owner (employee who created) a product ?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before asking questions, your current question lacks a lot of quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PrestaShop doesn't save the employee who create a product. Product don't have owner.

Although your module can use the hook `actionAddProductAfter` for instance and save the employee id inside a new table. This is fairly easy to do and you'll get what you need.